# How to nicely flatten pdf using PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox 2.0.4 and trying to set values to some fields.
I have simple textfields and comboboxes, and all the values are correctly set. But when I try to flatten the PDF, the combobox values disappear. 
How can I make it show the value after flattening?

To flatten the document I used AcroForm's flatten method.

I've tried to set fields read only, it did not help, I've also tried to set `needAppearances` to `false`, did not help either.

EDIT1: link for the pdf - http://www.ommf.gov.hu/letoltes.php?d_id=7122

EDIT2: code: https://gist.github.com/dernori/4246e35cf50dc3a4dfea71db68fda465

Comment: Please share the PDF in question and your pivotal code.

Comment: And update to 2.0.8.

Comment: Please also share your pivotal code. A first look at the PDF shows, though, that there is a usage rights signature in it. If you are not very careful, your operations on the file damage the signature making Adobe Reader revoking  the additional features which can also result in unexpected behavior. Furthermore, there is some JavaScript in your form which might influence the appearance of the PDF.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr the update helped on the comboboxes, thanks!

Comment: @mkl thanks for your comment! :) I added the code, but as I can see now only some of the simplest textfields will disappear after flattening. can you see some mistake in the code?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr yes but I made typos.. :)

Comment: Please post a code segment that sets one specific field with a specific value to show the effect, or just mention what value is to be set where. Your current code does not show what values are set.